# Which is the memory space for static variable declared inside a function?

Tags: c

We know that when a function is called a block of memory is pushed into the stack and when the function finishes its job the block of memory which was pushed earlier is now popped out.
Is it correct in all the circumstances. Even if the function contains declaration of static variables? If yes then how do the static variables retain their values? Are they assigned memory space in heap and not stack ?

Comment: I dont know what is .bss and .data and how they are related with heap and stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static and global variable in memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421254/static-and-global-variable-in-memory) along with a ton of others. Note all the "related" questions on the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @Brian the answer to that question does not specifically say if static variables are assigned in heap. Also I would like if someone can cite any trusted link

Comment: I can see some conflicting answers to the previous related questions. Hence please cite a link or answer if you are very sure.

Comment: For the Standard there is no Stack,Heap,Data Segment or BSS, So if by a credible link you mean the C standard, then you won't get any.

Comment: @Als so can i confidently say that the static variables are not given memory space along with the auto variables ( i.e. stack)

Comment: Yes, You can confidently say so because local variables on a stack are deallocated/thrashed/send to oblivion once the scope ends, while static variables live throughout the program lifetime and maintain their values.So even if the standard leaves out where to allocate variables as an implementation detail, static and local variables cannot have the same allocation strategy.

Comment: @Als is that the only conclusion which can be made about static variables. Can I also say that they may or may not share the same memory space as globals do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static local variables don't live on the stack, they live in the same memory as a global variable.  .bss is memory where global variables that are uninitialized will reside.  .data could hold variables declared with an initial value.

Comment: Can i simply say that they are assigned memory space on the heap. Or is there something which differentiates heap and .bss and .data

Comment: heap usually refers to space used for dynamic allocation via malloc, so no, your static variable will not consume heap space

Comment: so you mean there are 3 or more types of memory spaces. The heap, the stack and the one in which global or static variables are assigned space. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, that covers it in general.  In some cases you might have several more custom areas defined.  For example, on some embedded systems you may need variables to live in specific addresses, so you define new regions in your linker script and add pragmas in code to indicate that particular variables need to be placed in those sections

Comment: Is there a name for the third space. Is it a combination of .bss and .data ?

Answer (score 2):

An object declared with the `static` keyword has static storage duration. An object with static storage duration does not get deallocated when the execution exits the block where it is defined. The lifetime of a static object is the lifetime of the program: the object is created when the program starts and is destroyed when the program exits.

Comment: ya, but my question here is about the space which it consumes and not the time

Comment: @bubble this is not specified by the language as the language does not require a stack. However on implementations with a stack, `static` object are usually simply not stored on the stack. On Unix, you can expect `static` objects to be stored in .bss, .data or .rodata.