# What happens when static variable is declared twice?

Tags: c, static

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void func();

    int main()
    {
        static int b = 20;
        func();
    }

    void func()
    {
        static int b;
        printf("%d", b);
    }
```

Output: `0`

Is a new memory location created when the second static variable is declared?

Comment: second static variable scope in func()

Comment: You've answered your own question?!

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Each of your `b` variables is private to the function in which they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

> Is a new memory location created when the second static variable is declared?

Yes.
Both the variable `b` in `main` and `func` are different although they have same name. `static` keyword only change the lifetime of a variable not its visibility.

Comment: @YuHao; Agreed. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

`b` in `func` and `b` in `main` are two different variables, they are not related, and their scope is inside each function that they are in.

Answer (score 1):

when you declare a variable in your function

compiler first look the local variable in the current function

then if can not find it look for global variables

Answer (score 1):

Yes new memory location is created for above two static variables.

For abov code, Each static variable defined in the function call has scope for the function itself.

Refer

[Static and global variable in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421254/static-and-global-variable-in-memory)

Answer (score 1):

**"b"** variables are **private** because they are used in the **"function"**. Unique global varible can be used once but you can use same **local** variables **unlimited times**. 
Example-
 In this example I am declaring **Global variable** and **Private variable**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int second() ;
int main()
{
    char number;
    cout << "Please input a value\n"; 
    cin >> number;
    cout << " You selected: " << number; 
    second(); // This should work in a C program, how do I do it in C++
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

int second();
{
    char number;
    cout << "Please select another value...";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "You selected: " << number;
}
```