# Declare variable in global/function scope. Stack difference?

Tags: c++, memory, scope, stack

Why is there a different for stack variables if we declare them in the global or function scope? One of the two example crashes, because of stack overflow. But only the one, which define a variable inside the scope.

Does crash:

```
constexpr size_t MAX = 1000000;  // Customise

int main()
{
  int arr[MAX];

  return arr[MAX - 1];
}
```

Does not crash:

```
constexpr size_t MAX = 1000000;  // Customise

int arr[MAX];

int main()
{
  return arr[MAX - 1];
}
```

Info: Cygwin, GCC 4.9

Edit: So I know, the second example have is memory in the data segment. How big can the data segment be? Could it be so big as the heap area?

Comment: "different for stack variables" - well, because the second one *isn't* a stack variable. The stack is limited size, very small relative to the allowable size of the whole program. This is one good reason to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for very large arrays.

Comment: Global variables aren't actually stack variables. They're allocated in load time. Also, doesn't seem like it should crash, and when i tested it it didn't.

Comment: Hope [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment#Program_memory) helps.

Comment: @YamMarcovic it would depend on the stack size. Yours must be bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one

```
constexpr size_t MAX = 1000000;  // Customise

int main()
{
  int arr[MAX];

  return arr[MAX - 1];
}
```

You declare array in a function, so it goes to stack which is limited and will cause stack overflow.

The second one

```
constexpr size_t MAX = 1000000;  // Customise

int arr[MAX];

int main()
{
  return arr[MAX - 1];
}
```

You declare it at global, should be accesible between function so it goes to heap (rather big). So not using stack here.

Source : [Static and global variable in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421254/static-and-global-variable-in-memory)

Comment: Not to the heap (usually)

Comment: @YamMarcovic yeah, some specific segment i think. But in lecture i got heap for specific reason. I think it's more easy to taught in class.